# Linking libraries built with ICC with application built with GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, icc

I have a set of static libraries, say **lib1.a**, **lib2.a** and **lib3.a** which have been compiled using ICC (Intel C/C++ Compiler). I  used ICC with **-ipo -c** for compilation to create **.o** files and then XIAR (Intel Archiver) for creating **.a** libraries.

I want to give these three libraries to a client who does not have ICC and hence will be using GCC to compile and link her application with these libraries. Will the speed-gain (expected from cross-file optimizations due to libs built with **-ipo** option) not be achieved **at all** if she links these libraries using GCC?

[This page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522750) from Intel Website on "**GCC Compatibility and Interoperability**" states:

> Link-time optimization using the -ffat-lto-objects compiler option is
>   provided for gcc compatibility. This implies that ld and ar can be
>   used to link and archive object files, but by doing so you will lose
>   cross-file optimizations.

I am using icc version 13.1.0 (gcc version 4.6.0 compatibility) with gcc version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using -ipo the optimization will actually happen at the link stage.

During compilation (icc -c -ipo) the Intel compiler only stores additional information in the object files. This additional information is used at link stage to do the actual interprocedural optimization (ipo).

So in order to benefit from IPO you need to use the Intel compiler at compile **and** link stage.

Comment: As [this page](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-3F5EC717-AEC2-45C2-BC43-463939FB3118.htm) states, **Intel® C++ compiler will generate mock object files that only the compiler's linker (xilink.exe and xild) can understand**, I guess there is no way for GNU Linker to use the additional information contained in object files to do some optimization. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry I explained that not clear. Yes, the linker has to be the Intel linker as the GCC linker just ignores this additional information/mock objects/intermediate language.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Kittur (from Intel) has also confirmed it [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/544922).

Answer (score 1):

If you created the archive with xiar, then all the objects you want placed in the archive are compiled together using IPO and put into your static library. You'll end up with a real .a file that is optimized with -ipo.

You CAN give that library to anyone, and they will get the benefit of having the library itself cross compiled with -ipo, but the library code will not be mixed in other libraries of the users objects with which it's being linked.

Basically, you'll have a .a file that is fully optimized with -ipo (assuming all the objects in it were built with -ipo) that you can give to clients. The clients code will not "further" optimize with -ipo against your library.

Comment: You are right that the .a file is fully optimized with ipo (assuming all objs were built with -ipo). Additionally, Thus created archive has separate sections for real-object (**without ipo**) and mock-object (**ipo**) data. If I try to link this archive with Intel utilities (ICC, XILD), then it will use the mock-object data, ignoring real-object data completely. And if I try to link it with non-Intel compilers (GCC), then only real-object data will be used ignoring mock-object data. As a result, if I had to use GCC as linker, there is no point in compiling with **-ipo** option.